# Laravel 5.1.26 : MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219

Tags: php, laravel-5

I will get `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` when submitting a form in laravel

HTML file

```
<form action="{{ action('HomeController@store') }}" method="post">
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Im my routes.php

`Route::post('formaction','HomeController@store')`

Controller.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
   public function store(){
      echo 'form submitted';
    }
}
```

Why i will get MethodNotAllowedHttpException in my form action page?
I've refereed some questions related to this,but nothing help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if the form is using the POST method, you are sending the extra param `_method` which will let the framework know that you want to use that method instead. If you send that extra param then you should set the route accordingly:

```
Route::patch('formaction','HomeController@store');
```

Comment: After submitting form when i refresh the page form is again submitted and csrf is didnt worked here

Comment: What is returning the `store` method?

Comment: You should redirect after updating